# i cant install a driver for rtl8812bu on the rasberrypi (please help)

Tags: raspbian, wifi

for context i have a rasberrypi4 and Kernel: Linux 6.1.21-v8+
i have gotten myself a wifi dongle yet i have spent 2 days researching ways to get the driver installed with no luck if anyone knows of a way that will work with this version please please share.

Comment: *researching ways to get the driver installed* - what have you found so far? There's quite a few "how to" out there, don't want to suggest one you've already tried

Comment: I have tried pretty much the first few links I can’t really say which ones as my search history doesn’t save but most where from GitHub and I remember fastoe one or something